# To verify the completely positivity: about conditionally completely positive

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

I'm reading the paper *Assessing Non-Markovian Quantum Dynamics*, by M.M. Wolf (*[PRL 101, 150402 (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.150402)*, [*arXiv:0711.3174*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3172)). It mentions how to decide whether a generator is a valid Lindbladian generator, which means it can generate CPTP maps.

According to the paper,there are sufficient conditions: a,Hermitian. b,**conditionally complete positive**

I can't understand the explanation of **CCP** in the paper. Why it is a valid Lindbladian if projecting the generator onto the orth complement of the maximally entangled state and get the positive results?

Comment: conditional complete positivity seems to be defined in (2) in the (arxiv version of) the paper, as $\omega_\perp \hat L^\Gamma\omega_\perp\ge0$ with $\hat L^\Gamma$ Choi of $\hat L$, $\omega_\perp\equiv I-\omega$, and $\omega$ projector onto the maximally entangled state. Can you be more specific as to what you find unclear about it?

Comment: I don't quite understand why the positivity of Choi matrix is equivalent to the complete positivity of correspondent superoperator?